# iPython wrapping output

Tags: css, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm displaying pandas tables wider than 114 characters using print(df.head).  pandas column width is set to 500 using pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500).  But jupytr is wrapping the line at about 114 characters.  I tried setting the max width using the code below, but doesn't appear to influence width.

```
%%html
<style>
.output_wrapper, .output {
    height:auto !important;
    max-height:1000px;  /* your desired max-height here */
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.output_scroll {
    box-shadow:none !important;
    webkit-box-shadow:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for pandas, this should print out 320 characters for example

```
desired_width = 320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 10)
```